# Android Browser, when changing DOM body height, browser scrolls back to top

Tags: javascript, android, dom, browser

Happens using android 2.3.5. Having an element at the bottom of the site - that when you click it, expands. But when this gets clicked, the browser jumps back to top, thus losing 'focus' of the element. Any chance this can be avoided?

The browser also jumps back when just changing the height on the body element with javascript.